# Comparing size of ions lithium, gallium ions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, atomic-radius

How is the size of $\ce{Li+}$ ($\pu{0.68}$) larger than $\ce{Ga^3+}$ ($0.62$)?

This is very difficult for me to understand  why they say that size of Li+ with 3 protons and just 2 electrons should be considerably more than that of $\ce{Ga^3+}$. I understand the poor shielding effect of $\ce{3d^{10}}$ electrons but it isn't obvious to me why it will make its size smaller than $\ce{Li+}$ which has just one shell with 2 electrons and more effective nuclear charge. Where is my logic wrong?

Comment: Because removing *three* electrons from Ga leaves a much stronger net positive charge, pulling in the orbitals, than pulling *one* from Li.

Comment: We removed remove the 1 electron from 4p1 and then remove 2 electrons from 4s2 these three electrons where the ones on which the nucleus pulled on with more force but now they are not there.

Comment: @drmoishepippik but what about Ga3+ containing 3 shells and Li only one?

Comment: Could you link the source of the image?

Comment: @holgerfielder https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98166/comparing-size-of-ions?noredirect=1#comment181545_98166

Comment: @Jasmine I have removed the image because most of it was irrelevant to the discussion. Still, you need to link to the webpage from where you obtained the values. Note that the image was missing the distance units too (is it Angstrom or picometers?)

Comment: @gaurangtandon I meant to relate the size. I will take care next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *is* impressive.  What you may need to bear in mind is that as the nuclear charge increases, *all* the electron orbitals move in closer to the nucleus.  You may have been assuming, consciously or unconsciously, that the electron shells appear at a relatively fixed distance from the nucleus -- that is, that the n=1 shell is always at about the same distance from the nucleus, the n=2 shell is always at about the same additional distance, and so on.

Not the case!  For example, if you take a look at the quantum mechanical model of the hydrogen atom and solve it for a "hydrogen-like" atom with atomic number Z and one electron (so, He+, Li++, Be+3,....,U+92 ha ha) then you will find that the average orbital radius of the electron scales like 1/Z.  So if we ignored electron-electron repulsion entirely, the radius of each shell would decrease like 1/Z as Z increases.  That's quite a contraction.  It would mean that the n=1 shell in carbon, say, would be 1/6 the size of what it is in hydrogen.  In the case of Ga, Z=31, the n=1 shell would be 1/31 the size it is in H!  Each new shell would contract similarly.

So *in the absence of electron-electron repulsion* we would expect the size of atoms to shrink drastically as Z increases, going across the Periodic Table, and bumping up slightly at the beginning of each row with the addition of a new shell.  Of course, real atoms do have electron-electron repulsion, lots of it, so the effect is considerably muted.

Nevertheless, the size of atoms does shrink considerably going from left to right in the Periodic Table, and it's worth remembering this is because *all* of the electron shells shrink, not just the valence shell.

Comment: This surely helps. I didnt know that the size radius by 1/Z and i think it may even lead to repulsion between the electrons in 2 consecutive shells